# Anaconda を wget で毎回インストールし直さないと conda コマンドが使えない

Tags: python, aws, anaconda

AWSのターミナルにログインして `wget` でAnacondaをインストールすると、インストールはできるのですが、`packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx port 22: Broken pipe` と接続が切れた時に、またAnacondaをインストールしなければcondaコマンドが使えません。

なぜ毎回インストールしなければならないのでしょうか？何が原因でこうなっているのでしょうか？

---

**実行コマンド**

```
wget https://3230d63b5fc54e62148e-c95ac804525aac4b6dba79b00b39d1d3.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/Anaconda3-4.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

PATHが通っていないためと思われます。次のコマンドを実行後にcondaを実行してみてください。

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Anacondaを使うためには、毎回そのコマンドを実行する必要があります。それが面倒であれば、~/.bashrc に登録するようにしてください。

また、Anacondaをインストールする時には、"Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda3 install location to PATH in your /home//.bashrc ?"というオプションを選択する画面が表示されると思いますが、その時にyesと入力すると ~/.bashrcに自動で登録されます。

Linuxの場合は、そのオプションはデフォルトではNoになっています。Windowsの場合と違ってNoになっているのは、AnacondaへのPATHを通してしまうと、Linux側にインストールされているPythonが使えなくなったり、~/anaconda3/bin にインストールされているコマンドがOSのものより優先的に使われてしまうという問題があるためだと思われます。